# Can't arrange items to the expected position

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I've witten a script in vba to parse two categories from each container from a webpage. The scraper is able to parse them accordingly. The problem I'm facing at this moment is that I can't place these items across columns. If a column contains `views`, the next column should contains `votes` and so on. The way I'm expecting the result is more like:

```
column1   column2   column3   column4
9 views   0 vote    10 views   -2
```

This is my script so far:

```
Sub CollectInfo()
    Const URL As String = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim post As HTMLHtmlElement, R&, C&

    With Http
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    R = 1

    For Each post In Html.getElementsByClassName("question-summary")
        C = C + 1: Cells(R, C) = post.getElementsByClassName("views")(0).innerText
        Cells(R, C + 1) = post.getElementsByClassName("votes")(0).innerText
    Next post
End Sub
```

The way I tried is definitely leading me to the wrong placing. How can I fix it to serve the purpose? Btw, I do not wish to go for the `offset` (I meant `Range("A1").offset(,1)"`) looping ;rather, I wanna stick to the way I tried above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will show views and votes by turns. I changed `XMLHTTP60` to `MSXML2.XMLHTTP60`, because on my end it causes automation error.

```
  Sub CollectInfo()

    Const URL As String = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"
    Dim Http As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim post As HTMLHtmlElement, R&, C&

    With Http
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    R = 1

    For Each post In Html.getElementsByClassName("question-summary")
        C = C + 1
        Cells(R, C) = post.getElementsByClassName("views")(0).innerText
        C = C + 1
        Cells(R, C) = post.getElementsByClassName("votes")(0).innerText
    Next post

End Sub
```

Comment: Shame on me!! Yes, you made it. It seems my thinking was cloudy. Thanks.